# BAD_ACCESS when trying to free data when UIView to UIImage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, uiimage, cgimage

I intended to take a snapshot of a `UIView` that drawed by `OpenGL ES` into an `UIImage`, here is the code I used:

```
 if(context){
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFramebuffer);
    NSInteger dataLength = framebufferWidth * framebufferHeight * 4;

    GLubyte* data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength) ; // malloc(myDataLength);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, framebufferWidth, framebufferHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    // make data provider with data.
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataLength, NULL);

    // prep the ingredients
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = 4 * framebufferWidth;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    // make the cgimage
    CGImageRef result = CGImageCreate(framebufferWidth, framebufferHeight, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

    // then make the uiimage from that
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:result];
    CGImageRelease(result);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    //free(data);

    return image;
}
```

I was intended to use `free(data);` before `return`, but that would raises a `BAD_ACCESS` runtime error.

So my questions is, how to `free` properly? Or should I `free` them after the image releases?

Comment: Can you just log `data` before the release part of the code?

Comment: Have you tried using Apple's sample code instead? http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1704/_index.html

Comment: Can you put `free(data)` before your other releases and see what happens, like this, `free(data); CGImageRelease(result);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);`
    ?

Comment: @BlackFlam3 `data` is not nil before I `release` and it does not work to put `free` ahead of other releases

Comment: @trojanfoe That would generate an all-white `UIImage`

Comment: What? you want a method that doesn't crash **and** doesn't create an all-white image? :D  It's hard to believe (but possible) that Apple would publish such broken code; please re-check that the code is compatible with the classes you are using.

Comment: @trojanfoe I have tried to render it again and call this method before `presentRenderBuffer`. They all generates an all-white image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my current code and it works just fine.

```
if(context){ 
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFramebuffer);
    NSInteger dataLength = width * height * 4;
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = 4 * width;
    GLubyte* data = (GLubyte*)malloc(dataLength) ;
    glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

    // make upside down
    GLubyte* swp = (GLubyte*)malloc(width * 4);
    for (int h = 0; h < height / 2; h++) {
        memcpy(swp, data + (height - 1 - h) * bytesPerRow, bytesPerRow);
        memcpy(data + (height - 1 - h) * bytesPerRow, data + h * bytesPerRow, bytesPerRow);
        memcpy(data + h * bytesPerRow, swp, bytesPerRow);
    }

    NSData* nsData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:data length:dataLength freeWhenDone:YES];
    // make data provider with data.
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)nsData);

    // prep the ingredients
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    // make the cgimage
    CGImageRef result = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

    // then make the uiimage from that
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:result];
    CGImageRelease(result);

    return image;
 }
```

Comment: Tomas Camin is right. your code create memory leaks on data and swp. After malloc you have to call free(data) and provider callback is right way to do it. free(swp) call right after "make upside down" loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `CGDataProviderCreateWithData's` `CGDataProviderReleaseDataCallback` as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGDataProvider/Reference/reference.html).

Simply add the freeData function callback:

```
void freeData(void *info, const void *data, size_t size) 
{
    free((void*)data);
}
```

and pass it to `CGDataProviderCreateWithData`:

```
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, data, dataLength, freeData);
```

Comment: storeColor is the title of the debug window full of assembly code. btw it works now.. So weird